# how to create a readonly session in nHiberate?

Tags: nhibernate

Is it possible to creat a readonly connection in nHibernate ?

Read-only : where nHibernate will not flush out any changes to the underlying database implicitly or  explicitly.

When closing a nhibernate connection it does automatically flush out the changes to the persistent object.

Setting the flush mode to *never* is one way - but is reversable (i.e some code can reset the flush mode).

Comment: I know this is an ancient (in Internet time) question, but what's the reason for your concern about this being "reversable"?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I think you've already found the solution, setting flush mode to never.  Yes, it is changeable but even if it wasn't, code could simply create another session that had a different flush mode.

I think the appropriate solution is to *suggest* read-only with `session.FlushMode = FlushMode.Never` and *enforce it* by using a connection to the database that only has SELECT permissions (or whatever is appropriate for your situation).  Maintaining separate ISessionFactory factories might help by allowing something like `ReadOnlySessionFactory.Create()`.

Answer (score 6):

Take a look at Read Only entities that became available in NHibernate 3.1 GA
https://nhibernate.jira.com/browse/NH-908

Answer (score 2):

There is a newer readonly feature in NHibernate (I don't know which version, but it's in 3.3.0 for sure). You can set the session to read only using this:

```
session.DefaultReadOnly = true
```

It disables the cache for old values and therefore improves performance and memory consumption.

There is a [chapter about read-only entities](http://nhibernate.info/doc/nhibernate-reference/readonly.html) in the [NHibernate reference documentation](http://nhibernate.info/doc/nhibernate-reference/index.html).

Answer (score 0):

Accumulating updates, and just never flushing seems like a bad solution to me. 
I posted a similar question. The solution provided uses a different approach. All the events are set to empty, and thus ignored. My feeling is that it's a better approach.

I am surprised that this is not easier to do. I like the entity framework approach of using an extension method .AsNoTracking() which ensures that read only queries remain that way.

[How to create an NHibernate read-only session with Fluent NHibernate that doesn't accumulate updates?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12667634/fluent-nhibernate-read-only-session)

Comment: No, updates don't accumulate after setting session.FlushMode = FlushMode.Never. I checked it by overriding SaveOrUpdateEventListeners like in your question, and listener does not called  with FlushMode.Never. In your solution NoOpEventListener is called for each change