# How to create an NHibernate read-only session with Fluent NHibernate that doesn't accumulate updates?

Tags: nhibernate, configuration, readonly

What configuration options should be used to construct a session that will not accumulate updates, and will always remain read only?

It would seem that replacing the first or second level cache for a read only version might be the answer, how is that achieved using fluent configuration?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See [how to create a readonly session in nHiberate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/768191/how-to-create-a-readonly-session-in-nhiberate)

Alternatively you can replace the default Save/Update/Delete event listeners with your own implementations that do nothing

To do so, in your NHibernate configuration you will need to do something like:

```
Fluently.Configure()
    // your config goes here
    .ExposeConfiguration(
        x => x.EventListeners.SaveOrUpdateEventListeners = 
           new ISaveOrUpdateEventListener[ ]{new NoOpEventListener() } ;
    // etc for other types
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for that. I did see the post you mention, but it would seem counter intuitive to me to accumulate all the updates and just never flush them. It seems like a gross waste of resources. I think this approach is much better. I added a link there.

Comment: No, updates don't accumulate after setting session.FlushMode = FlushMode.Never. I checked it by overriding SaveOrUpdateEventListeners like in your question, and listener does not called  with FlushMode.Never. In your solution NoOpEventListener is called for each change